# Is it possible to create and run a bigquery temp table locally in memory?

Tags: java, google-bigquery

I'm trying to create a local temp bigquery table in memory for testing purposes.  I'm doing this in Java.  I'm not finding a ton of info on this, it seems like BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService() could do it, but the docs say that it looks for the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable for where to go.

Is there a way to do it locally?

Comment: Hi there and welcome to SO, Have you tried following the documentation on how to use BigQuery Client lib described in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java). Can you edit your question with a more detail code example which better explain your problem

Comment: Hi @TamirKlein, thanks.  I know it's a little confusing.  So I've checked out the documentation, I'm having a hard time finding out what happens when there's no credentials supplied, if it'll run on my local machine as a result.  Basically what I'm trying to do is make it unit testable.  Spotify has a scala lib that does this, https://github.com/spotify/scio/blob/master/scio-bigquery/src/main/scala/com/spotify/scio/bigquery/MockBigQuery.scala

Comment: You first need to set up your service account on your local machine as described in the link I provided. Once set you will be able to run a query and get the response. So you have 2 steps you need to complete. If you find and issue please update your question with a detail error message you are getting and explain the step you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with Java and you are looking for a way to create unit tests with a mock of BigQuery, there's a GitHub project with a class that could do that for you:

- https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigdata-interop
- https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigdata-interop/blob/master/bigquery/src/test/java/com/google/cloud/hadoop/io/bigquery/BigQueryUtilsTest.java

`BigQueryUtilsTest.java` relies on Mockito and it's under an Apache-2.0 license (if you need to modify it for your environment).

Comment: Do we have something like this for Python?

Comment: Do we have something like this for Scala also?

Comment: My apologies for not having an answer to these questions, I moved on to Snowflake